# Can't load OpenCL runtime / or fails to load for xmrig

Tags: drivers, graphics, amdgpu, opencl, amdgpu-pro

I have updated from Ubuntu 16.04 to **20.04**. While doing so the uprade failed and I ended up doing a fresh install of 20.04. Fortunately, I have my home folder on another drive so that was saved. There was still a lot to recover. The last item I am stuck on is getting my **AMD Radeon 580 GPU** working. AMD does not support drivers for Ubuntu after 16.04. I tried installing **OPENCL** from this below page. *And, I hope I installed the right software.*

https://rocmdocs.amd.com/en/latest/Installation_Guide/Installation-Guide.html

While following along with the advice of this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=efKjfBkjPlM

The object is to do a bit of GPU crypto mining using the **xmrig** program while my computer is idle.

To check for successful completion I have rocminfo and clinfo comands.

Result of rocminfo is:

joe@joeslinux:~$ /opt/rocm/bin/rocminfo

```
ROCk module is loaded
joe is member of video group
=====================    
HSA System Attributes    
=====================    
Runtime Version:         1.1
System Timestamp Freq.:  1000.000000MHz
Sig. Max Wait Duration:  18446744073709551615 (0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF) (timestamp count)
Machine Model:           LARGE                              
System Endianness:       LITTLE                             

==========               
HSA Agents               
==========               
*******                  
Agent 1                  
*******                  
  Name:                    AMD Ryzen Threadripper 1950X 16-Core Processor
  Marketing Name:          AMD Ryzen Threadripper 1950X 16-Core Processor
  Vendor Name:             CPU                                
  Feature:                 None specified                     
  Profile:                 FULL_PROFILE                       
  Float Round Mode:        NEAR                               
  Max Queue Number:        0(0x0)                             
  Queue Min Size:          0(0x0)                             
  Queue Max Size:          0(0x0)                             
  Queue Type:              MULTI                              
  Node:                    0                                  
  Device Type:             CPU                                
  Cache Info:              
    L1:                      32768(0x8000) KB                   
  Chip ID:                 0(0x0)                             
  Cacheline Size:          64(0x40)                           
  Max Clock Freq. (MHz):   3400                               
  BDFID:                   0                                  
  Internal Node ID:        0                                  
  Compute Unit:            32                                 
  SIMDs per CU:            0                                  
  Shader Engines:          0                                  
  Shader Arrs. per Eng.:   0                                  
  WatchPts on Addr. Ranges:1                                  
  Features:                None
  Pool Info:               
    Pool 1                   
      Segment:                 GLOBAL; FLAGS: KERNARG, FINE GRAINED
      Size:                    65778612(0x3ebb3b4) KB             
      Allocatable:             TRUE                               
      Alloc Granule:           4KB                                
      Alloc Alignment:         4KB                                
      Acessible by all:        TRUE                               
    Pool 2                   
      Segment:                 GLOBAL; FLAGS: COARSE GRAINED      
      Size:                    65778612(0x3ebb3b4) KB             
      Allocatable:             TRUE                               
      Alloc Granule:           4KB                                
      Alloc Alignment:         4KB                                
      Acessible by all:        TRUE                               
  ISA Info:                
    N/A                      
*******                  
Agent 2                  
*******                  
  Name:                    gfx803                             
  Marketing Name:          Ellesmere [Radeon RX 470/480/570/570X/580/580X/590]
  Vendor Name:             AMD                                
  Feature:                 KERNEL_DISPATCH                    
  Profile:                 BASE_PROFILE                       
  Float Round Mode:        NEAR                               
  Max Queue Number:        128(0x80)                          
  Queue Min Size:          4096(0x1000)                       
  Queue Max Size:          131072(0x20000)                    
  Queue Type:              MULTI                              
  Node:                    1                                  
  Device Type:             GPU                                
  Cache Info:              
    L1:                      16(0x10) KB                        
  Chip ID:                 26591(0x67df)                      
  Cacheline Size:          64(0x40)                           
  Max Clock Freq. (MHz):   1340                               
  BDFID:                   16640                              
  Internal Node ID:        1                                  
  Compute Unit:            36                                 
  SIMDs per CU:            4                                  
  Shader Engines:          4                                  
  Shader Arrs. per Eng.:   1                                  
  WatchPts on Addr. Ranges:4                                  
  Features:                KERNEL_DISPATCH 
  Fast F16 Operation:      FALSE                              
  Wavefront Size:          64(0x40)                           
  Workgroup Max Size:      1024(0x400)                        
  Workgroup Max Size per Dimension:
    x                        1024(0x400)                        
    y                        1024(0x400)                        
    z                        1024(0x400)                        
  Max Waves Per CU:        40(0x28)                           
  Max Work-item Per CU:    2560(0xa00)                        
  Grid Max Size:           4294967295(0xffffffff)             
  Grid Max Size per Dimension:
    x                        4294967295(0xffffffff)             
    y                        4294967295(0xffffffff)             
    z                        4294967295(0xffffffff)             
  Max fbarriers/Workgrp:   32                                 
  Pool Info:               
    Pool 1                   
      Segment:                 GLOBAL; FLAGS: COARSE GRAINED      
      Size:                    8388608(0x800000) KB               
      Allocatable:             TRUE                               
      Alloc Granule:           4KB                                
      Alloc Alignment:         4KB                                
      Acessible by all:        FALSE                              
    Pool 2                   
      Segment:                 GROUP                              
      Size:                    64(0x40) KB                        
      Allocatable:             FALSE                              
      Alloc Granule:           0KB                                
      Alloc Alignment:         0KB                                
      Acessible by all:        FALSE                              
  ISA Info:                
    ISA 1                    
      Name:                    amdgcn-amd-amdhsa--gfx803          
      Machine Models:          HSA_MACHINE_MODEL_LARGE            
      Profiles:                HSA_PROFILE_BASE                   
      Default Rounding Mode:   NEAR                               
      Default Rounding Mode:   NEAR                               
      Fast f16:                TRUE                               
      Workgroup Max Size:      1024(0x400)                        
      Workgroup Max Size per Dimension:
        x                        1024(0x400)                        
        y                        1024(0x400)                        
        z                        1024(0x400)                        
      Grid Max Size:           4294967295(0xffffffff)             
      Grid Max Size per Dimension:
        x                        4294967295(0xffffffff)             
        y                        4294967295(0xffffffff)             
        z                        4294967295(0xffffffff)             
      FBarrier Max Size:       32                                 
*** Done ***
```

clinfo is a stranger.
Running clinfo, I got:

```
joe@joeslinux:~$ clinfo
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cl::Error'
  what():  clGetPlatformIDs
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Running it from the directory got a different error:

```
joe@joeslinux:~$ /opt/rocm/opencl/bin/x86_64/clinfo
ERROR: clGetPlatformIDs(-1001)
```

Running it with sudo from the directory got what appears to be valid output.
joe@joeslinux:~$ sudo /opt/rocm/opencl/bin/x86_64/clinfo

```
Number of platforms:                 1
  Platform Profile:              FULL_PROFILE
  Platform Version:              OpenCL 2.1 AMD-APP (3098.0)
  Platform Name:                 AMD Accelerated Parallel Processing
  Platform Vendor:               Advanced Micro Devices, Inc.
  Platform Extensions:               cl_khr_icd cl_amd_event_callback cl_amd_offline_devices 


  Platform Name:                 AMD Accelerated Parallel Processing
Number of devices:               1
  Device Type:                   CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU
  Vendor ID:                     1002h
  Board name:                    Ellesmere [Radeon RX 470/480/570/570X/580/580X/590]
  Device Topology:               PCI[ B#65, D#0, F#0 ]
  Max compute units:                 36
  Max work items dimensions:             3
    Max work items[0]:               1024
    Max work items[1]:               1024
    Max work items[2]:               1024
  Max work group size:               256
  Preferred vector width char:           4
  Preferred vector width short:          2
  Preferred vector width int:            1
  Preferred vector width long:           1
  Preferred vector width float:          1
  Preferred vector width double:         1
  Native vector width char:          4
  Native vector width short:             2
  Native vector width int:           1
  Native vector width long:          1
  Native vector width float:             1
  Native vector width double:            1
  Max clock frequency:               1340Mhz
  Address bits:                  64
  Max memory allocation:             7301444403
  Image support:                 Yes
  Max number of images read arguments:       128
  Max number of images write arguments:      8
  Max image 2D width:                16384
  Max image 2D height:               16384
  Max image 3D width:                2048
  Max image 3D height:               2048
  Max image 3D depth:                2048
  Max samplers within kernel:            26591
  Max size of kernel argument:           1024
  Alignment (bits) of base address:      1024
  Minimum alignment (bytes) for any datatype:    128
  Single precision floating point capability
    Denorms:                     No
    Quiet NaNs:                  Yes
    Round to nearest even:           Yes
    Round to zero:               Yes
    Round to +ve and infinity:           Yes
    IEEE754-2008 fused multiply-add:         Yes
  Cache type:                    Read/Write
  Cache line size:               64
  Cache size:                    16384
  Global memory size:                8589934592
  Constant buffer size:              7301444403
  Max number of constant args:           8
  Local memory type:                 Scratchpad
  Local memory size:                 65536
  Max pipe arguments:                16
  Max pipe active reservations:          16
  Max pipe packet size:              3006477107
  Max global variable size:          7301444403
  Max global variable preferred total size:  8589934592
  Max read/write image args:             64
  Max on device events:              1024
  Queue on device max size:          8388608
  Max on device queues:              1
  Queue on device preferred size:        262144
  SVM capabilities:              
    Coarse grain buffer:             Yes
    Fine grain buffer:               Yes
    Fine grain system:               No
    Atomics:                     No
  Preferred platform atomic alignment:       0
  Preferred global atomic alignment:         0
  Preferred local atomic alignment:      0
  Kernel Preferred work group size multiple:     64
  Error correction support:          0
  Unified memory for Host and Device:        0
  Profiling timer resolution:            1
  Device endianess:              Little
  Available:                     Yes
  Compiler available:                Yes
  Execution capabilities:                
    Execute OpenCL kernels:          Yes
    Execute native function:             No
  Queue on Host properties:              
    Out-of-Order:                No
    Profiling :                  Yes
  Queue on Device properties:                
    Out-of-Order:                Yes
    Profiling :                  Yes
  Platform ID:                   0x7fe7119b5d30
  Name:                      gfx803
  Vendor:                    Advanced Micro Devices, Inc.
  Device OpenCL C version:           OpenCL C 2.0 
  Driver version:                3098.0 (HSA1.1,LC)
  Profile:                   FULL_PROFILE
  Version:                   OpenCL 1.2 
  Extensions:                    cl_khr_fp64 cl_khr_global_int32_base_atomics cl_khr_global_int32_extended_atomics cl_khr_local_int32_base_atomics cl_khr_local_int32_extended_atomics cl_khr_int64_base_atomics cl_khr_int64_extended_atomics cl_khr_3d_image_writes cl_khr_byte_addressable_store cl_khr_fp16 cl_khr_gl_sharing cl_amd_device_attribute_query cl_amd_media_ops cl_amd_media_ops2 cl_khr_image2d_from_buffer cl_khr_subgroups cl_khr_depth_images cl_amd_copy_buffer_p2p cl_amd_assembly_program
```

clinfo and it’s folder are owned by 1001. I know that this means there is no owner 1001.

```
drwxrwxr-x  5 1001 1001 4096 May 17 22:28 opencl
```

I changed owner to root. Then I ran the clinfo command agaion, but that made no difference.

The program which I am trying to run is xmrig.

Here is the error line:

```
./xmrig ...

* OPENCL       disabled (failed to load OpenCL runtime)
```

*Also note, that I have not run this xmrig mining program before, that is while on 16.04. I had used a different miner at that time.*

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found instructions that work!

I've tried to install OpenCl from numerous instructions I found all around the web. Most were an exercise in frustration. This is the one that worked for me. https://gist.github.com/kytulendu/3351b5d0b4f947e19df36b1ea3c95cbe

Answer (score 0):

```
usermod -a -G render your_user
apt install opencl-headers
```